# App Dependency wierd behaviour AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

First I am very very new to AngularJS so it might be a newbe problem.

I have a declaration of my app Dependancies in my app.js file:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
        'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
        'ngSanitize',                   // ngSanitize
    ])
})();
```

When i added the following dependency: nestedDataTable to the end of the list(or the beginning) like this:

```
(function () {
angular.module('inspinia', [
    'ui.router',                    // Routing
    'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
    'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
    'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
    'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
    'ngSanitize',                   // ngSanitize
    'nestedDataTable'
])})();
```

The functionality that `nestedDataTable` was responsible for didn't work.

only after i added a new `function()` that adds the above dependency alone, the functionality worked. like this:

```
(function () {
angular.module('inspinia', [
    'ui.router',                    // Routing
    'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
    'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
    'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
    'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
    'ngSanitize'                    // ngSanitize
])
})();
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("inspinia", ["nestedDataTable"])
})();
```

It also doesn't work if i'll switch the order of the 2 functions.
it doesn't make any sense, but hey, Im a newbe ;)

Can someone think of something that might be the reason?

Comment: Did you get an error in the console on app boostrap?  Maybe a syntax comma error?  In your first code snippet, you have an extra trailing comma which shoudn't be there.

Comment: Yes i know, that was a mistake i made here but the extra comma is not in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to my fault (Newbe as i mentioned) forgot to add the proper js files to index.html